# How to install sqldiff tool in Fedora 31

Tags: fedora, software-installation, sqlite

I want to compare two sqlite databases, but there seems to be no [sqldiff](https://www.sqlite.org/sqldiff.html) tool in sqlite package. I also can't find any other package providing sqldiff. I'm quite new to Fedora. Forgive my ignorance, but I'm really stucked. Sqldiff seems to me so basic and popular tool so I can't imagine there isn't any in default Fedora repos.

```
$ sqlite3 --version
3.30.0 2019-10-04 15:03:17
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/sqldiff` is provided by the package `sqlite-tools`, only available for Fedora 32.

Comment: @Knud Larsen Thanks for the info. After upgrade to 32 I will tidy up things.

Answer (score 1):

Found answer on [Fedora Forum](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?323474-How-can-I-install-sqldiff). I simply forgot about COPR.

There is also an option to download precompiled binaries from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html (sqlite-tools-linux-XXX.zip). It works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 31: Providing `/usr/bin/sqldiff ← sqlite-tools` the classic way

```
$ rpm -Uvh Downloads/sqlite-3.31.1-1.fc32.src.rpm
$ cd rpmbuild/SPECS/
# dnf builddep --spec sqlite.spec

$ rpmbuild -bb sqlite.spec
.
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/sqlite-devel-3.31.1-1.fc31.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/lemon-3.31.1-1.fc31.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/sqlite-libs-3.31.1-1.fc31.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/sqlite-tcl-3.31.1-1.fc31.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/sqlite-3.31.1-1.fc31.x86_64.rpm

Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/sqlite-tools-3.31.1-1.fc31.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/sqlite-analyzer-3.31.1-1.fc31.x86_64.rpm
```